# Understanding multiple tasks with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to learn how to use python asyncio using this tutorial: http://terriblecode.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python/ and applying it to what I would like to do.

I'm trying to get urls from an api and then visit those urls to gather more information which is contained within them. To get started I was going to follow the tutorial and save the information locally and then get the information from the .json files rather than hit the API.

I'm using python 3.5 so I just changed the f strings to ones which will work but the code is very similar.

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aiohttp
import json

base_url = 'https://demo.com/api/'

HEADERS = {
    "API-Key": "<removed>",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'Testing API'
}

async def get_bad_urls(url_args):
    endpoint = 'search/'
    url = base_url + endpoint
    print("Collecting urls...")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS) as resp:
            data = await resp.json()
            for url in (data['results']):
                url_args.append(url['_id'])


async def get_url_data(url_uuid):
    endpoint = 'result/' + url_uuid
    url = base_url + endpoint
    print("Getting URL result details...")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS) as resp:
            print(resp)
            data = await resp.text()
    async with aiofiles.open(url_uuid + ".json", 'w') as file:
        await file.write(data)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
url_args = []
loop.run_until_complete(get_bad_urls(url_args))
print(url_args)
loop.run_until_complete(
asyncio.gather(
    *(get_url_data(*uuid) for uuid in url_args)
)
)
```

The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/linux/PycharmProjects/url/main.py", line 44, in 
>       *(get_url_data(*uuid) for uuid in url_args)   File "/home/linux/PycharmProjects/url/main.py", line 44, in 
>       *(get_url_data(*uuid) for uuid in url_args) TypeError: get_url_data() takes 1 positional argument but 36 were given

Any pointers in the right direction even if that is scrapping what I have here and going about it differently, would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're passing `*uuid` instead of `uuid`.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Thanks for pointing that out, I overlooked that more than a couple times clearly. Your suggestion works. I tried removing the * before but obviously the first one is required. 

asyncio.gather(*(get_url_data(uuid) for uuid in url_args)))

I'm not sure I understand why the first one is required. If I try to run it without I get "RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <coroutine object get_url_data at 0x7f5cbe207eb8>" - Can you explain this, if you have the time please?

Comment: The first one is required because of the [signature of `gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather); it wants each coroutine/future as a separate argument. Think of it as `gather(get_url_data(url_args[0]), get_url_data(url_args[1]), ...)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did read before asking but I'm going to have to go read more about it. Thanks again for the reply it's very helpful.